# Make npm warn me about missing packages

Tags: npm

Is there a way to make npm tell me if there are new packages in the `package.json` that have yet to be installed. This comes up when a team member pulls down new code that adds a dependency and then the build fails because they need to run npm install. I'd like to make it so the build will explicitly warn that a package hasn't been installed yet rather than just failing in a confusing way.

Answer (score 0):

`npm ls` displays errors for any missing packages at the end of its output:

```
npm ERR! missing: main-loop@^3.1.0, required by your-project@0.0.0
```